How do i have my mailer.js to send OTP code to email and not on my terminal?
I created a school result portal and when signing up it keeps sending the OTP to my terminal and not to the email I use. Also, once I finished registering and input the OTP from the terminal my dashboard comes out empty
I tried working on the server.js auth.js and my mailer.js also changed the gmail and password on .env but still not sending code to the gmail.

Ensure your email configuration in mailer.js (or the equivalent file) is set up correctly. Here’s a basic example using nodemailer:
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL, // Your email
        pass: process.env.PASSWORD // Your password or app password
    }
});

const sendOTP = (recipientEmail, otp) => {
    const mailOptions = {
        from: process.env.EMAIL,
        to: recipientEmail,
        subject: 'Your OTP Code',
        text: `Your OTP code is ${otp}`
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    });
};

module.exports = sendOTP;

Make sure your .env file has the correct environment variables:
EMAIL=your-email@gmail.com
PASSWORD=your-email-password

Ensure that when you generate the OTP, you are calling the sendOTP function with the correct parameters.
const sendOTP = require('./mailer'); // Adjust path if necessary

router.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
    const { email } = req.body;
    const otp = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000); // Generate a 6-digit OTP

    // Save OTP and user data to database or session (not shown here for brevity)

    sendOTP(email, otp); // Send the OTP to the user's email
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'OTP sent to your email!' });
});   

